# Set row color with closedXML based on column value

Tags: closedxml

I am trying to write Excel file from datatable with VB.NET. I am able to achieve few excel operations also. Now I want to colour a row based on cell value of a particular column (Col-4 for example). Here is my Excel file -

[Here is my Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyYkl.png)

[I want to achieve like this -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr3tm.png)

Looking some guidance to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add conditional formatting. For example:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.AddWorksheet("Sheet1");

ws.FirstCell().SetValue(1)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(1)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(2)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(3)
  .CellBelow().SetValue(4);

ws.RangeUsed().AddConditionalFormat().WhenBetween(2, 3)
  .Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);
```

Reference: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Conditional-Formatting

Comment: Thanks. I satisfied the requirement by adding following code -

Dim nonEmptyDataRows2 = ws1.RowsUsed
                For Each dataRow1 In nonEmptyDataRows2
                    'for row number check

                    Dim cell1 As String = dataRow1.Cell(29).Value

                    If cell1 = "0" Then
                        dataRow1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Yellow
                    ElseIf cell1 = "1" Then
                        dataRow1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Green
                    End If

                Next

Comment: @RituparnoBhattacharya is that C#?